# How to get only numbers from the row?

Tags: r

I'd like to ask if there is any efficient way to get the values from the row instead of writing:

```
as.numeric(data[2,]
```

Example:

```
data <- data.frame(Names=c('Train','Car', 'Plane', 'Bicycle'),
                   Day1 = c(15,22,36,22),
                   Day2 = c(33,57,2,41),
                   Day3 = c(87,32,15,25),
                   Day4 = c(14,2,6,33),
                   Day5 = c(41,76,11,44),
                   Day6 = c(11,12,35,25),
                   Day7 = c(52,2,42,55))
```

Not correct:

```
> data[2,]
  Names Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5 Day6 Day7
2   Car   22   57   32    2   76   12    2
```

Correct output:

```
> as.numeric(data[2,])
[1]  2 22 57 32  2 76 12  2
```

Any "nicer" way to get such output ?

Comment: Do you want the output to be a vector or a data.frame?

Comment: `as.numeric` transform `car` in `2`, is that what you want?

Comment: I don't think "data" is the data frame you expected. Where did the 2 come from in your as.numeric ? edit : welp @Victorp got me

Comment: output as a vector. You are right this 2 in the begining shouldn't be there. I just want to get values from each day for a specific row. Is it possible to call a row same as a column with data$xxx ?

Comment: `DayX` are the columns in `data`, so `data$Day2` works.

Comment: but what about rows ? like data$Car ? such fast access to the rows is possible ?

Comment: No, use `t()` for transpose your data, `Car` will be a column and `data$Car` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should convert your data.frame into a matrix:

```
mat <- as.matrix(data[, -1])
rownames(mat) <- data[, 1]
mat[2,]
```